# How to remove the history of the "A word or phrase in the file" field in the search?

Tags: windows-xp, search, history

I want to get rid of them all.

For a li'l explanation on what field. Go into the search of file, move into the field with that name and without writing anything else, press the down arrow (you have to had used it before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at the previous entries in the "A word or phrase in the file:" field, move the selection to a word and as you do, hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> on each selected/highlighted entry. This will remove them one by one without dealing with the registry.

If you want to play around in the registry (Start > Run > regedit), follow the path to:

> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru

Then proceed to delete all the numbered folders underneath that node.

If you would like to prevent it from saving next time, right-click and select Permissions on the `ACMru` node. For each group or user, check the Deny box and save.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an XP machine to test on, but check out Clear the ["Search for files and folders" history in Windows XP](http://www.winxptutor.com/searchmru.htm).  You could also search the registry for the phrase you want to remove (here's a loaded shotgun with a hair trigger, now don't go shotin' yourself in the foot.)